# Discord Bot in Python: Using parameters to make commands

Tags: python, discord.py, command

So, while I was making my command script I was wondering how to get 2 quick answers like other bots. I saw that some bots when typing the command like /coinflip it was asking me for a parameter where it was asking which side, like heads or tails and it was showing 2 "quick answers", like showing the 2 options: heads or tails, and I wanted to make this same thing with my bot. I tried looking for a tutorial but I don't find anything helpful. Could you guys help?

My idea:

```
@bot.tree.command(name="createcoinflip", description=f"Creates a coinflip based on the arguments.")
async def describe(interaction: discord.Interaction, amount: int, side: commands.Option(choices=["Heads", "Tails", "Random"])): 
#make pop up these 3 answers when typing in discord the command and being in the parameter "side"
    await interaction.send(f"You chose {side} with an amount of {amount} gems.")
```

Well, I tried using `commands.Option(choices=["Heads", "Tails", "Random"])` but that isn't a thing. I know I can make a condition if the parameter == "heads" but I want it to also pop up as "tip" to don't have to manually type it every time.

Also, I was trying to make optional arguments, like when doing /balance it asks for the player but if the person that does the command doesn't type something, it will be automatically chose the user of the person that sent that command.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question, check the documentation for using [autocomplete](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html#discord.app_commands.Command.autocomplete).

About the second question, you can define parameters as optional by setting a default value for it (`None` for example). Here's an example command that has an optional `player` parameter:

```py
@bot.tree.command(name="profile")
async def profile(interaction: discord.Interaction, player: discord.Member = None):
    """View profile

    Args:
        player: view another player's profile
    """

    # if the user do not enter a member, player will be None
    # so, if player is None, we will atribute interaction.user to player 
    player = player or interaction.user
```

Comment: If one only needs to choose between two options, you can also use `typing.Literal['heads', 'tails']` which is way better in this case if you ask me.